# Ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ QOpenGLWidget. QtCreator

Tags: qtcreator

Скопировал из документации https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html пример. Вставил в заголовочный файл, оставил одну функцию и компилятор ругается на функцию `glClearColor`.  Файл `socoban.h`

```css
#ifndef SOCOBAN_H
#define SOCOBAN_H


#include <QOpenGLWidget>

class Socoban : public QOpenGLWidget
{
public:
    Socoban(QWidget *parent) : QOpenGLWidget(parent) { }

protected:
    void initializeGL() override
    {
        // Set up the rendering context, load shaders and other resources, etc.:
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    void resizeGL(int w, int h) override
    {
        // Update projection matrix and other size related settings:

    }

    void paintGL() override
    {
        // Draw the scene:
    }

};
#endif // SOCOBAN_H
```

> mainwindow.obj:-1: ошибка: LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ __imp__glClearColor@16 в функции "protected: virtual void __thiscall Socoban::initializeGL(void)" (?initializeGL@Socoban@@MAEXXZ)

Если бы я вставил еще какую нибудЬ OpenGL-фукнцию, типа `glOrto` он бы так же и на нее ругался.

```css
//mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "socoban.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

    Socoban *soco;
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H


//mainwindow.cpp

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    soco = new Socoban(this);
    soco->setGeometry(0,0,100,100);
    delete soco;
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

//mainwindow.cpp
```

Comment: QT += opengl вот такая штука в pro-файле есть?

Comment: да, но в документации написано приписать `widgets`. В общем так `QT       += core gui widgets opengl`

Comment: очистить и пересобрать

Comment: Удалял папку `build-..` и потом `пересобрать все` сто раз так делал, не помогает

Comment: для Qt4 `opengl`, для Qt5 `widgets`

Comment: Ну так QOpenGLWidget он и наследует QWidget. Я сначала использовал QGraphicsScene, но если обьектов больше 500 то он их рисует долго. Почитал в интернете, а QOpenGLWidget рисует тысячи обьектов и при этом очень много. Начал разбираться

Answer (score 0):

Qt5 по крайней мере для Visual Studio не добавляет в проект opengl библиотеку, это надо делать вручную, добавьте в проект:

`LIBS += -lopengl32`

Comment: Приписал. Перестало выдавать такие ошибки. Копировал из интернета примеры как рисовать обьекты, но он только фон мне разукрашивает. Не знаете ли почему? (Могу скинуть ссылку на код)

Comment: я редко в opengl работаю, но в qt5 надо смотреть в какой версии вы работаете v1 или старше, если старше то уже надо делать шейдеры и в них могут быть ошибки

Comment: А как узнать версию?

Comment: наверное `QOpenGLContext::openGLModuleType`  и `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`